# Modified bubble sort, but not working correctly

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

The task was to modify bubble sort so that it’s bidirectional.

This means the "`in`" index will first carry the largest item from left to right, but when it reaches "`out`", it will reverse and carry the smallest item from right to left.

The `bubbleSort()` method is just the normal way it was presented in an example.

My code is in the method **`bidiBubbleSort()`**.

For some reason when I ran the program it gave me an output that was sorted, but not correctly.

I manually did each step on a piece a paper with a pencil but I don't know what I'm overlooking.

> Unsorted: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

and

> Sorted: 6 4 2 1 3 5 7

```
class ArrayBub
{
   private long[] a;                            // ref to array a
   private int nElems;                          // number of data items
// --------------------------------------------------------------
   public ArrayBub(int max)                     // constructor
   {
      a = new long[max];                        // create the array
      nElems = 0;                               // no items yet
   }
// --------------------------------------------------------------
   public void insert(long value)               // put element into array
   {
      a[nElems] = value;                        // insert it
      nElems++;                                 // increment size
   }
// --------------------------------------------------------------
   public void display()                        // displays array contents
   {
      for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)               // for each element,
         System.out.print(a[j] + " ");          // display it
      System.out.println("");
   }
// Beginning of my code -------------------------------------------------------
   public void bidiBubbleSort()
   {
      int out, x, y;
      int in = 0;

      for(x=0, out=nElems-1; out>x; out--, x++) // outer loop (backward)
         for(in=x; in<out+1; in++)              // inner loop (forward)
            if( in<out )
               if( a[in] > a[in+1] )            // out of order?
                  swap(in, in+1);               // swap them
               else                             // (in==out)
                  for(y=out-1; y>x; y--)        // reverse 
                     if( a[y] < a[y-1] )
                        swap(y, y-1);
   }
// End of my code -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void bubbleSort()
   {  
      int out, in;

      for(out=nElems-1; out>1; out--)            // outer loop (backward)
         for(in=0; in<out; in++)                 // inner loop (forward)
            if( a[in] > a[in+1] )                // out of order?
               swap(in, in+1);                   // swap them
   }                                             // end bubbleSort()

   private void swap(int one, int two)
   {
      long temp = a[one];
      a[one] = a[two];
      a[two] = temp;
   }
// --------------------------------------------------------------
}                                               // end class ArrayBub

class BubbleSortApp
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      int maxSize = 100;                        // array size
      ArrayBub arr;                             // reference to array
      arr = new ArrayBub(maxSize);              // create the array

      arr.insert(7);                            // insert 7 items
      arr.insert(6);
      arr.insert(5);
      arr.insert(4);
      arr.insert(3);
      arr.insert(2);
      arr.insert(1);

      arr.display();                            // display items

      arr.bidiBubbleSort();                     // bidirectional bubble sort

      arr.display();                            // display them again
      }                                         // end main()
}                                               // end class BubbleSortApp
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of bidirectional bubble sort or cocktail sort is to solve the problem of lowest values (aka turtles) at the end of unsorted list to move to the beginning of list faster than a conventional bubble sort.

Keeping this objective in mind, you need to understand bidirectional bubble sort sorts from both ends. ie., **Beginning to end of the list, End to beginning of the list *every* pass**.

Your current implementation seems to unsuccessfully tweak the conventional bubble sort. My advice would to forget the implementation of bubble sort and code with the above stated objective w.r.to bubble sort in mind.

To start you off, below is a hint:

> Decide the exit of your outer loop dynamically with a condition to check
>   if the list has been sorted or not. Do not rely on the counter on the
>   outer loop like the conventional bubble sort does.

If you are still not able to solve it, take a peek at wikipedia article and then implement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort. *Only look at it if you are not able to solve it!*